# How can I keep a user logged in after they log in once on my flask website?

Tags: python, flask

```
from yff import app, db, bcrypt, mail
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request
from yff.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm, RequestResetForm, ResetPasswordForm
from yff.models import Image, User
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
from flask_mail import Message
from random import sample
from string import ascii_letters, digits

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return render_template("index.html", current_user=current_user)
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/create-account", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def createacc():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    isValid = form.validate_on_submit()
    if isValid:
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f"Your account has been created succcessfully. You can now log in.")
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        return render_template('createacc.html', title="Register", form=form)

    

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    isValid = form.validate_on_submit()
    if isValid:
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            if next_page:
                return redirect(next_page)
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check your email and password.')
    return render_template('login.html', title="Login", form=form)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/account')
@login_required
def account():
    return render_template('account.html')

@app.route('/read/<string:post_name>')
def read(post_name):
    # page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Image.query.filter_by(post_name=post_name)
    # posts = Image.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
    # print(posts.items)

    return render_template('readmang.html', posts=posts)

@app.route('/user/<string:username>')
def user(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404()
    posts = Image.query.filter_by(user_id=user.id)
    print(type(posts))
    return render_template('user.html', user=user, posts=posts)

def send_reset_email(user):
    token = user.get_reset_token()
    msg = Message('Password Reset Request', 
    sender=os.environ.get('your_fan_fiction_email'), 
    recipients=[user.email])
    msg.body = f'''
To reset your password, visit the following link:
{url_for('reset_password', token=token, _external=True)}

    If you did not send this request, simply ignore it and no changes will be made.
'''
    mail.send(msg)

@app.route('/reset-password', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def request_token():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RequestResetForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        send_reset_email(user)
        return 'An email with the reset password link has been sent to you.'
    return render_template('reset_token.html', form=form, title='Reset password')

@app.route('/reset-password/<token>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reset_password(token):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    user = User.verify_secret_token(token)
    if user is None:
        flash('That is an invalid or expired token')
    form = ResetPasswordForm()
    isValid = form.validate_on_submit()
    if isValid:
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user.password = hashed_password
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f"Your password has been changed.")
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('reset_password.html', form=form, title='Reset password')
```

Here, I want to use sessions to store the user info data. The pages contain content unique to the current_user so I somehow want to use sessions to authenticate the current_user. What I mean is that the current_user.is_authenticated function should return True if the user has logged in once and the session has the data for the login credentials of the user. How can I do that? Also, I want the session data to not be deleted when the user closes their browser. I have a decent idea of how I will implement using sessions to store data but I have no clue how I will make the session data not get deleted when the browser is closed or how I will make the current_user.is_authenticated function return true if the sessions have the users' login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

In your **init**.py file you need the following, also make sure you import your secret key in this file, info here -> https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#sessions

The documents here walk you through using flask_login if you need help implementing it. https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'
...
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'
enter code here
...
```

In your models file. Include the following for your users table

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
...
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    ...
```